# Can python `except` match against all errors in the chain?

Tags: python, exception

I have a python application which constructs a long error chain with multiple `raise from` clauses. I'm interested defining a specific `except` block to catch one of the values that may occur deep within the chain. It appears that python `except` only checks against the first error in the chain. Is there a standard way to traverse the chain similar to `errors.is` in go?

Example:

```
class CustomException1(Exception):
  pass

class CustomException2(Exception):
  pass

class CustomException3(Exception):
  pass

def func_1():
    try:
        raise Exception("test failure")
    except Exception:
        raise CustomException1()


def func_2():
    try:
        func_1()
    except Exception as e:
        raise CustomException2() from e


def func_3():
    try:
        func_2()
    except Exception as e:
        raise CustomException3() from e


def func_4():
    try:
        func_3()
    except CustomException1:
        print("do something specific for CustomException1")
        pass
    except Exception:
        print("general exception handler")
        pass

func_4()
```

I ran the above code and saw the output "general exception handler". I'd like the exception to be matched by `CustomException1` clause. Is there a standard method for traversing the chain?

Comment: At the call of `func_3`, it is catching the `CustomException3`, that's why it didn't `CustomException1` there.

Comment: @Zero Yup my question is how to have except match against any error in the chain

Comment: The "nested" exceptions are *attributes* of the enclosing exception, not a "peer" that's immediately visible to the trying code. You might want to look at PEP 654 and use exception groups.

Comment: There really isn't a "chain".  When func_1 raises `CustomException1`, it gets "caught" in `func_2`.  At that point, it's lifetime and usefulness is finished.  `func_2` then raises a brand new exception.  If you want to propagate the earlier exception, you'd either need to `raise e`. in `func_2`, or skip the `try`/`except` altogether.

Comment: re exception groups - Interesting I wasn't aware of these! They seem to almost meet my use case. It looks like the one awkward part is that unmatched errors in the group are treated as unhandled.

Comment: re the "chain" - since each error is set as the `__cause__` on the parent error I'd imagine matching could be done by recursing through the set of error `__cause__` values

Comment: @AlexKaplan If you catch the entire exception group, you can handle the errors you want and ignore the rest. `except*` is special syntax for catching *only* a specific exception (or group thereof) and letting the rest propagate. `raise ... from ...` is more, I think, for giving *context* to an exception, rather than consolidating multiple exceptions from multiple sources.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting in Python 3.11, you can use [exception groups](https://peps.python.org/pep-0654/) to package multiple exceptions into a single package with arbitrary structure. Here, we're still preserving the linear structure implied by the call stack, but we don't need to explicitly traverse that chain to find an exception of type `CustomeException1`. (Though you can: `except*` is syntactic sugar for manipulating a caught `ExceptionGroup` using its API, including the `subgroup`, `split`, and `derive` methods.)

```
class CustomException1(Exception): pass    
class CustomException2(Exception): pass    
class CustomException3(Exception): pass


def func_1():
    raise CustomException1()


def func_2():
    try:
        func_1()
    except Exception as e:
        raise ExceptionGroup("from func_2", [CustomException2(), e])


def func_3():
    try:
        func_2()
    except ExceptionGroup as eg:
        raise ExceptionGroup("from func3", [CustomException3(), eg])


def func_4():
    try:
        func_3()
    except* CustomException1:
        print("do something specific for CustomException1")
    except* Exception:
        print("general exception handler")

func_4()
```

When you run the script, you'll see the following output:

```
do something specific for CustomException1
general exception handler
```

Note that the `except*` clause *extracts* `CustomException1` from wherever in the hierarchy it may be found; the catcher need not parse the exception group manually (though it is possible using the `split` method, which is what `except*` uses in its implementation.) Also note that unlike `except`, `except*` can *continue* matching exceptions after each handler has executed.